# Google Maps API save markers and load them on next start

Tags: android, google-maps-api-2, markers

Pretty lame title, but that's what I am trying to figure out. I want simply to be able to create markers on long click on the map, and then save those markers in db, preferences, array list, I don't know, just in some persistent storage, where they won't be wiped on the next start of application. I want to keep it simple, if it's possible with just shared preference, then please tell me how.
Here's the code

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements ParsingCallback {

    private GoogleMap mMap;
    Marker marker = null;
    String s;
    GoogleMapOptions options;
    LocationManager lm;
    LatLng userLocation;
    Location location;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        options = new GoogleMapOptions();
        mMap = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
        lm = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        listOfPoints = new ArrayList<SavedMarkers>();
        mMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_SATELLITE);
        mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
        mMap.getUiSettings().setCompassEnabled(true);
        mMap.getUiSettings().setRotateGesturesEnabled(true);
        mMap.getUiSettings().setZoomGesturesEnabled(true);
        mMap.getUiSettings().setMyLocationButtonEnabled(true);
        }

        /** On Map Long Click */
        mMap.setOnMapLongClickListener(new OnMapLongClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onMapLongClick(LatLng arg0) {
                mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(arg0).title(arg0.toString()));
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Marker Created", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: what's the problem? Every time you create market just add it's properties to some array. And then reuse this array.

Comment: if I knew how, I woulndn't have asked at all

Comment: your question is to general

Comment: @Malachiasz It's not too general. Please read it again, the guy has carefully showed what he has done so far.


Why downvote?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Gson to serialize and deserialize your array list of `SavedMarkers`.

```
Type listOfMarkers = new TypeToken<List<SavedMarkers>>(){}.getType();
String stringToSaveInSharedPreferences = gson.toJson(list, listOfMarkers);
List<SavedMarker> markers = gson.fromJson(stringRetrievedFromSharedPreferences,listOfMarkers)
```

;